# Azure Service Fabric service level scaling

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We have a scenario on service fabric where we are receiving messages from multiple users and buffering them in a queue
and multiple stateful services act as consumers.

We want to "scale out" those consumers based on queue load,
but the load is instantaneous at one minute thousand of messages and at next nothing.
Creation and deletion of consumers take time in minutes. We don't want messages to starve and also don't want to take
decision instantly.

1. Does service fabric provide any scaling option on the service instance/replica level in this scenario
2. if not what would be best approach to scale out the consumers

Comment: Are you wanting to scale out hardware? Add more nodes to the cluster based on demand?

Comment: No, just want to add/ remove number of named services.